# Можно ли говорить в дне (от слова день)?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Задача: я знаю что в сутках 24 часа а можно ли говорить: "В дне 24 часа"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь, видимо, наложились две трудности, фонетичесчкая - скопление согласных и слабая семантическая сочетаемость. Очень вычурно выглядит это "в дне", единственное употребление - именно то, что вы назвали. "В сутках" ещё может иметь какое-то альтернативеное употребление, наподобие "В сутках выделяют четыре времени (суток)". Аналогично "в году" и т.д. "В дне" и придумать что-то сложно.
Тем более, что есть вариант "день состоит из...".

Так что вариант "в дне" следует считать скорее окказиональным, чем нормативным образованием.

Answer (score 1):

Теоретически можно, так как одно из значений слова день - это сутки. (меня не было 5 дней=не было 5 суток). А практически все-таки закрепилось употребление именно "в сутках 24 часа"

Answer (score 1):

Следует отметить, что у слова "день" есть два значения. Первое - это светлое время суток. Т.е. антоним к слову "ночь". При этом вполне допустимо употребление вида "я иду работать в ночь". Думаю, что слово день тоже можно так употребить ("работаю в день", но не "в дне"). Второе значение - синомим суток. В этом случае обычно говорят, что "в сутках 24 часа".

Единственный вариант, когда такое употребление допустимо, например, в следующих словосочетаниях: "в дне русского языка приняли участие представители иностранных государств". Но это еще одно значение - день как мероприятие.

Еще нюанс, что "в дне" очень напоминает склонение слова "дно". "В морском дне зарыты сокровища" :-)

Comment: >>>"в дне русского языка приняли участие представители иностранных государств".   
   
Да, не сообразил. правда это не совсем тот "день", о котором шла речь.